PDF empty in Android when using Expo React Native
sorry for my bad english, i'm a beginner, i want to generate pdf with html and download it into downloads, so i try like the expo-print documentation but the problem it give me an empty pdf with 0kb size in my brother phone (redmi note 10S), and everything works perfect in my phone (huawei y8 prime).


import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { themeColors } from "../../theme";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as Print from "expo-print";
import { shareAsync } from "expo-sharing";

const html = `
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  </head>
  <body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 50px; font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-weight: normal;">
      Hello World!
    </h1>
    <img
      src="https://d30j33t1r58ioz.cloudfront.net/static/guides/sdk.png"
      style="width: 90vw;" />
  </body>
</html>
`;

const CreatelunchSheet = () => {

const [selectedPrinter, setSelectedPrinter] = useState();

const print = async () => {
await Print.printToFileAsync({
      html,
      printerUrl: selectedPrinter?.url, // iOS only
    });
}

const selectPrinter = async () => {
    const printer = await Print.selectPrinterAsync(); // iOS only
    setSelectedPrinter(printer);
  };

return (
<SafeAreaView>
<TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              marginLeft: screenWidth * 0.05,
              width: screenWidth * 0.2,
              borderColor: themeColors.bgColor(1),
            }}
            onPress={print}
            className=" p-1 flex justify-center items-center  rounded-md border "
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: "arabswell_1",
                fontSize: 22,
              }}
              className=""
            >
              download
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {Platform.OS === "ios" && (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "white",
                  marginLeft: screenWidth * 0.05,
                  width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                }}
                onPress={selectPrinter}
                className=" p-1 flex justify-center items-center  rounded-md border "
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: "arabswell_1",
                    fontSize: 22,
                  }}
                  className=""
                >
                  select printer
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          )}
)
</SafeAreaView>
}

export default CreatelunchSheet;

